# Which datepicker library does Chronoforms 8 use and how is it possible to change the week start day to monday?

Tags: javascript, joomla, chronoforms

I have a Joomla website that uses Chronoforms 8 and I want to change the starting day of the week from sunday to monday, ie. the locale to `fi`. There is no documentation on Chronoforms' website on this issue and this specific version. The datepicker seems to be initialized in the file `administrator/components/com_chronoforms8/assets/nui.min.js`. I found a possible candidate for a javascript framework called "Nui": https://github.com/netherjs/nui However I am no way confident that this really is the framework Chronoforms 8 uses. The documentation of the mentioned framework has nothing about a datepicker. None of the arguments given to the constructor in `nui.min.js` hint anything about the ability to set a locale or otherwise tweak the starting date. So if there is any knowledge out here about the precise framework used, so that I could learn from it's documentation, I would highly appreciate it. Answers on how to actually change the starting day are also appreciated. "It can't be done" is also an acceptable answer. In that case a suggestion on how to replace the datepicker with another one would be the absolute ninja move.